# Merging multiple log files into single log file in sorted order based on time stamp using python in windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone please help me for below scenario:

**Input File1:**

```
abc.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-4-2020 8:8:52.786  [3636] Handshake value
Executing end handlier

abc.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.583  [3760] Create the general message 
Error Occured!! 30-4-2020 8:9:29.93  [2932] WARNING cannot remove qid
def.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.584  [3636] Create the general different message
```

**Input File 2:**

```
abc1.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.786  [3636] Handshake value 
abc1.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:52.58  [3760] Create the general message 
def1.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.53  [3636] Create the general different message
```

similarly....

**Input File N:**
...........

**Output File(1,2,-----N):**

```
abc.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-4-2020 8:8:52.786  [3636] Handshake value 
Executing end handlier
Error Occured!! 30-4-2020 8:9:29.93  [2932] WARNING cannot remove qid
abc.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.583  [3760] Create the general message 
abc1.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.786  [3636] Handshake value
def1.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.53  [3636] Create the general different message 
def.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.584  [3636] Create the general different message 
abc1.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:52.58  [3760] Create the general message
```

Please help to generate sorted log based on date and timestamp shown in bold letter in output file.
**Please note input file contains space and statements without timestamp and also contains error case.**

Comment: How far have you got with coding this? Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: The log files seems to be following a particular format:

<exe-generating-log> <fn-name> <some-id> <date-time> <pid-may-be> <operation> <msg>

Is this true for all the log files?

Comment: Yeah your understanding is correct. But in error cases it wont show the <exe-generating-log> <fn-name> <some-id>. Example: "Error Occured!! 30-4-2020 8:9:29.93  [2932] WARNING cannot remove qid ". I need to consider the error cases also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `datefinder` for DateTime extraction and `pandas` for sorting by DateTime.

```py
import os
# pip install datefinder
import datefinder
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

PATH = './input_files/'
```

```py
# a dictonary with key - datetime and values - substrings
df_dict = dict()
for in_file in os.listdir(PATH):
    # read input files one by one
    input_file = open(os.path.join(PATH,in_file)).read()
    # to store prev datetime to handle lines with no datetime
    prev_dt = 0
    for line in input_file.splitlines():
        # parse lines one by one
        if line.strip():
            pre, dt, post, raw_dt = '', 0, '', 0
            # using datefinder to extract datetime
            for match in datefinder.find_dates(line, index=True, source=True):
                # change valid year conditions accoring to use_case
                if match[0].year == 2020:
                    dt, pre, raw_dt, post  = match[1], line[:match[2][0]], match[1], line[match[2][1]:]
            if dt:
                prev_dt = dt
                df_dict[dt] = [pre, raw_dt, post]
            else:
                df_dict[prev_dt].append(line)
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dt_dict, orient='index')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
next_lines = df.pop(3)
df = pd.concat([df,next_lines]).dropna(how='all').fillna('').sort_index()

output =df[df.columns].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
output.to_csv('output.txt', header=False, index=None)
```

**Output:**

```
abc.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-4-2020 8:8:52.786 [3636] Handshake value
Executing end handlier  
Error Occured!! 30-4-2020 8:9:29.93 [2932] WARNING cannot remove qid
def1.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.53 [3636] Create the general different message
abc.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.583 [3760] Create the general message 
def.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.584 [3636] Create the general different message
abc1.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.786 [3636] Handshake value 
abc1.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:52.58 [3760] Create the general message
```

Comment: I am getting unresolved import pandas error. i am executing this program in VS Code

Comment: you need to install `pandas` library from terminal - using `pip install pandas`

Comment: Thanks its worked..But the output file format is changed. I need output in same format as like input.

Comment: @PrinceCady I have made changes to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, sorry to bother you again, what if  Input log contains error case, spaces and statements without time stamp. If line is not having timestamp please put after that earlier line as shown in output. This is my exact scenarist for testing you can copy paste the input files( I have edited my original post)

Comment: @PrinceCady code is modified according to the new log examples, also if anyone wants to fix for edge cases/optimization, please share/modify.

Answer (score 2):

For each line in both files, use a regular expression to extract the timestamp from the current line, convert the timestamp to a `datetime.datetime` object, and sort the collection of `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
def main():

    import re
    from datetime import datetime

    with open("log1.txt", "r") as log_1, open("log2.txt", "r") as log_2:
        all_lines = log_1.read().splitlines() + log_2.read().splitlines()

    for line in sorted(all_lines, key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(re.search("\\] ([^\\[]+) \\[", s).group(1), "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")):
        print(line)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
abc1.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-4-2020 8:8:51.786 [3636] Handshake value from driver = 1
abc.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-4-2020 8:8:52.786 [3636] Handshake value from driver = 1
def1.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.53 [3636] Create the general different message
abc.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.583 [3760] Create the general message
def.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.584 [3636] Create the general different message
abc1.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:52.58 [3760] Create the general message
>>>
```

Unfortunately, your data is bad. The first line of your second log file contains a date which does not exist - the 31st of april, 2020. The code I posted only works because I changed that one line to the 30th.

EDIT - For multiple files, you can use a `contextlib.ExitStack` as a context manager:

```
def main():

    from pathlib import Path
    from contextlib import ExitStack

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        def get_line():
            for file in (stack.enter_context(path.open()) for path in Path("logs/").glob("*.txt")):
                for line in file.read().splitlines():
                    yield line
        all_lines = list(get_line())
    print(all_lines)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

EDIT - Thanks for the new log files. Putting everything together:

```
def main():

    from pathlib import Path
    from contextlib import ExitStack
    import re
    from datetime import datetime
    from itertools import groupby

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        def get_line():
            for file in (stack.enter_context(path.open()) for path in Path("logs/").glob("*.txt")):
                for line in filter(None, file.read().splitlines()):
                    yield line
        all_lines = list(get_line())

    pattern = "(?P<timestamp>{}-{}-{} {}:{}:{}\\.{})".format(*["\\d+"] * 7)
    strptime_fmt = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f"

    def get_group():
        group = []
        for line in all_lines:
            match = re.search(pattern, line)
            if group:
                if match is None:
                    group.append(line)
                else:
                    yield group
                    group = [line]
            else:
                if match is not None:
                    group.append(line)
        yield group

    for group in sorted(list(get_group()), key=lambda g: datetime.strptime(re.search(pattern, g[0]).group("timestamp"), strptime_fmt)):
        for line in group:
            print(line)
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
abc.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-4-2020 8:8:52.786  [3636] Handshake value
Executing end handlier
Error Occured!! 30-4-2020 8:9:29.93  [2932] WARNING cannot remove qid
def1.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.53  [3636] Create the general different message
abc.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.583  [3760] Create the general message 
def.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.584  [3636] Create the general different message
abc1.exe TryEndHand [520] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.786  [3636] Handshake value 
abc1.exe QueueSharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:52.58  [3760] Create the general message 
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually i have multiple input log files, which take input from the folder. Folder contains more than 20 files. Unfortunately, above code wont work for  multiple files. Can you please help me with multiple files?

Comment: Thanks i will check for it

Comment: In multiple file case,date and time logic is missing

Comment: for 1st case(for only two files), i have tried, it throws exception saying "unconverted data remains:" at for loop.

Comment: @PrinceCady Try changing the regular expression pattern to `"\\] (.+?\\.\\d+) \\["`

Comment: I have changed but getting exception "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" at for loop.

Comment: @PrinceCady could you provide some more data from the logs you have? Obviously the regular expression pattern does not match the data you have. Maybe just update your original post and add a link to one or more of your logs, possibly on pastebin.

Comment: @ Paul M I have edited the question. Please copy those input files contents. Now Input log contains error case, spaces and statements without time stamp. If line is not having timestamp please put after that earlier line as shown in output. This is my exact scenarist for testing you can copy paste the input files

Comment: @PrinceCady I've updated my answer one more time - look at the code I posted at the very bottom.

Comment: Thanks Paul it's working. Can you please explain pattern part for matching the date format? Why you have multiplied by 7? Here what is the significance of yield?

Comment: @PrinceCady Glad it's working! I could have written the regular expression pattern as `"(?P<timestamp>\\d+-\\d+-\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+\\.\\d+)"` without the `.format` at the end, but that is a bit difficult to look at I think. The `.format` at the end just creates a list of seven `"\\d+"`s (one for each `{}`), and then inserts them into the original string. I'm using yield to create generators - they're basically functions with state. I'm sure there are other ways of doing this, but it's just the first solution I came up with to handle your specific needs and data.

Comment: @PrinceCady For the `get_line` generator, I'm using `yield` to essentially create a big list containing all the lines of all logs (by using `all_lines = list(get_line())`). For the `get_group` generator, I'm using yield to group certain lines from logs together, so that later when they are sorted they are not separated. My code also relies on the assumption that any given log does not start with an entry that does not contain a timestamp. If that were the case, it would group that line with the last group of the previous log - I have a feeling that's not the case though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, sorry to bother you  again, what is mean by "re.search(pattern, g[0]).group("timestamp")," ? why you have written ?P<timestamp> in pattern?

Comment: `?P<...>` is how one can create named regex capturing groups in Python. It's definitely not required - I named the capturing group so that I can do `re.search(...).group("timestamp")` rather than `re.search(...).group(1)`

Comment: Thanks for clarification.But  If you check the output, one line is missing "def1.exe SharedCreateNamed [488] 30-5-2020 8:8:51.53  [3636] Create the general different message". Every last line of second input file is not considered in implementation. Is something is wrong?

Comment: @PrinceCady Good catch! `get_group` was missing a yield at the end. I've updated the code.